# post data to RESTapi angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, vmware-clarity

Hi I am new to angular 6 I am trying to post data to web api but I am getting below error

**Exception: "400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"**

please telll me where I am going wrong, Thanks in advance

my service:

```
addIncidents(newIncidents: Incidents): Observable<Incidents> {
return this.http.post<Incidents>('api/v1/events', newIncidents, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    })
});
```

my component:

```
saveIncidents(formValues: any): void {
const newIncidents: Incidents = <Incidents>formValues;
console.log(newIncidents);
this.dataStorageService.addIncidents(newIncidents)
.subscribe(
  (data: Incidents) => console.log(data),
  (err: any) => console.log(err)
);
}
```

Incidents Model

```
export interface Incidents {

Incident_Start_Time: string;
Title: string;
Description: string;
Ticket: string;
}
```

html button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveIncidents()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You don't need to include the content type header. Angular does this automatically for application/json.

Comment: What does the shape of `Incidents` look like?

Comment: apply JSON.stringify(newIncidents) and try out

Answer (score 2):

On the click, you are calling the `saveIncidents()` method with no parameters. On the `saveIncidents()` method, instead, you expect one parameter and you send it as body request. But that variable is undefined, and the body of your request will be empty.

For this reason, you should provide a parameter in your `(click)` event. That parameter, I guess, would contain all the values of the form. In this case, you should set a template variable in the form element:

```
<form #incidents="ngForm" ...>
```

Then you can pass this variable to the method:

```
(click)="saveIncidents(incidents)"
```

This could require some transformation

Comment: Hi Thanks, But I am getting {"Exception":"'events'"}, in place of data in below line of code (data: Incidents) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)), I think post is not happening..

Comment: Hi Thanks, I tried posting hard coded data and its posting successfully, since now I am using Model.ts I am confused how to send data in below format, like data inside events below is the format where I want to send 

'events': [{
  Incident_Start_Time: string;
  Title: string;
  Description: string;
  Ticket: string;
       }
     ]

Answer (score 0):

It is not expecting content-type as JSON.

Just remove the headers or change it to `"text/plain"`.

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```